# Automated integration tests on deployed Java EE environment?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jakarta-ee

Our team is currently introducing automated testing to an existing Java EE web application that is deployed on Weblogic. We've had success with unit testing using JUnit and Mockito which are automatically run when our app is built and deployed by Jenkins.

Integration testing has been more challenging because our application relies on components provided by the Java EE container such as WorkManager. There are several Spring beans which require these components to initialize properly. One way we've been able to get around it is to create custom application context configuration files which create mocks of the components that we don't really need for testing but still require to initialize the bean. This has been somewhat of a maintenance nightmare because each integration test needs it's own config and some can be quite involved.

What we really want is to be able to have the entire application initialized with the normal configuration used in a deployed environment when running our integration tests. Is there a way to have integration tests automatically execute after deployment through Jenkins or another tool?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check [Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html), it can run test in your containers. Even remote ones.

I qoute:

> No more mocks. No more container lifecycle and deployment hassles.
>   Just real tests!

Comment: As the maintainer of the WebLogic 10.3.x/12c integration for Arquillian, I would recommend it. However I havent tested the Arquillian Spring extension against the WLS containers.